# How to find and move from the current directory in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to move a script from the directory I'm in to another directory after I have performed a find in the current directory. Although I don't get an error nothing happens. I don't know why. Can you help?

```
 find . -name ScriptsFlowchart.xml -execdir mv {} Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/{} \;
```

Comment: So you want to move the file `ScriptsFlowchart.xml` from whatever directory it is currently in to `Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts`? Is `Users` in the root of your file system, i.e. should it be `/Users`?

Comment: Yes Users is the root

Comment: Ah yes that works. Thanks  find . -name ScriptsFlowchart.xml -execdir mv "{}" /Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/{} \;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `-exec` instead of `-execdir` and drop `{}` in target definition.

```
find . -name ScriptsFlowchart.xml -exec mv {} Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/ \;
```

`{}` will retrieve the file path relative to current dir. So you must run the `mv` command from the current dir as well (using `-exec`).

From [`find` manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) page:

> -execdir command ;
>
> Like -exec, but the specified command is **run from the subdirectory containing the matched file**, which is not normally the directory in which you started find.

If that's in a bash script, try reading `$?` right after running the command to check if there were any errors (if equals `0`, runs successfully).